# How to convert EPSG:4326 point to X,Y tile coordinates

Tags: postgis, wgs84, vector-tiles

I'm trying to convert my geometry points in SRID 4326 I have stored in my DB to obtain tile coordinates (X,Y) for a given zoom level.

I've been doing it in my node server like this:

```
function long2tile(lon,zoom1) { 
tt = Number(lon);
return (Math.floor((tt+180)/360*Math.pow(2,zoom1)));
}

function lat2tile(lat,zoom2)  { 
return (Math.floor((1-Math.log(Math.tan(lat*Math.PI/180) + 1/Math.cos(lat*Math.PI/180))/Math.PI)/2 *Math.pow(2,zoom2))); 
}
```

For EPSG 4326 GPS coordinates (-71.1043 42.315)

I get this with my code

```
x:79295
y: 97002
```

I tried to do it with PostGIS like this

```
SELECT ST_AsText(ST_Transform(ST_GeomFromText('POINT(-71.1043 42.315)',4326),3857)) As wgs_geom;
```

I get this:
POINT(-7915294.469212161 5208282.331887754)|

but it,s not really a tile. Not sure how to use PostGIS to obtain tile coordinates for Mapbox vector tiles. I can keep doing it upstream with code but I would prefer to use PostGIS to obtain the coordinates.

Comment: You're asking postgis for a point not a tile X,Y. I think you'll need to divide by the scale factor and 256 (or your tile size)

Comment: I haven't found a postgis function to do that, I've been looking and I guess I thought a point could be a X,Y tile coordinate but I guess I was wrong

Comment: I would imagine that you would need to write your own function to do that

Comment: TOok me hours but I found this guy who's doing it, I thought postgis had some magic that could do it with one single callhttps://petewarden.com/2013/04/09/converting-to-and-from-google-map-tile-coordinates-in-postgis/

Comment: I can't for the life of me think of a reason why anyone would want to do this - but please answer your question in case any one else is

Comment: We are working on a fixed zoom level, so selecting the data I need is done by using where clause with tile bounds instead of ST_TileEnvelope, I could be wrong but we are far from being PostGIS experts and I was leaning towards a solution to get features that are located in fixed tiles for fast computation of a cost optimization

Comment: I'd expect a spatial index to be quicker

Comment: So you suggest a GIST index would be a better choice to query rows inside a specific envelope.

Comment: yes, there are years of optimisation in the indexes and query planner, it will almost always beat an ad hoc solution